# Help with DOS script (grab specific data from a file)

Tags: md5, dos

I need to grab just the md5 value from a file and make it a variable which I can use to compare to another md5 value.  The problem is this file looks like this:

a7393f772e34ca16a5854e80d9ec6704 md5

How do I open the file and only grab the actual number in DOS?  (Not the "md5" And set it as a variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do that with a batch file on MSDOS.  However, an NT/W2K/XP/etc. batch file can do it this way:

```
for /F "tokens=1" %%A in (md5list.txt) do set result=%%A
echo result is %result%
```

Comment: Thanks Wallyk.  I am running this as a .bat file, doesn't that use MS-DOS?  I will be running this in a Win2003 env.  I put your command in a .bat file and ran it and this was the output:

C:\ipod>test.bat

C:\ipod>for /F "tokens=1" %A in (file.txt) do set result=%A

C:\ipod>set result={\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss
\fcharset0

C:\ipod>set result={\*\generator

C:\ipod>set result=}

C:\ipod>echo result is }
result is }

Comment: No, it won't use MSDOS unless you invoke command.com, and even then it's not really MSDOS.

It looks like file.txt isn't formatted as expected.

Comment: @Steve: It appears as though your file.txt file is in fact an .rtf format file. Save it as plain text and try again.

Comment: I have one problem, my file never uses the same name so I cannot use a text file like list.txt. We automatically download two files a .dat file and a .md5 file.  Both of them have a unique filename which changes everytime (V2,V3,etc).  Essentially I run the .dat file through an md5 app and it produces the correct md5 which I want to compare to the .md5 file (after I grep out just the number) But when I tried to run the script with the solution you provided I just changed the (list.txt) to (*.md5) but it failed.  Any other way to grep out the number using an *.md5 file in your solution?

Comment: I just tested and if I specify the entire .md5 filename it works fine but is it possible to use a wildcard with this command?  This will be the only md5 file in the directory.

Comment: If you know you've only got one .md5 file in the subdirectory, why not just rename it first : REN *.md5 list.txt
This will work fine providing there's just one .md5 there.